# Bash or zsh conditional patterns and variable expansions

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables, templates, string-manipulation

Suppose I want to generate a filename based on some given variables.

```
track=01
title="Some title"
album="Some album"
echo ${track}. ${title} (${album})
```

->  `01. Some title (Some album)`

Now in the case `$album` is empty I would get

->`01. Some title ()`

I would rather want in that case the parenthesis to be removed:

->`01. Some title`

What I want is something similar to the templates used in **foobar** like this:

%track%. %title% [(%album%)]

Is it possible to do it in bash (or zsh) but in a single expression like the above and not using if...fi nor nothing like that.

Answer (score 4):

bash: yes, but it's not very pretty:

```bsh
filename="${track}. ${title}${album:+ ($album)}"
```

The `${var:+value}` expands to "value" if $var is both set and non-empty.

Demonstrating:

```bsh
$ album="Some album"
$ filename="${track}. ${title}${album:+ ($album)}"
$ declare -p filename
declare -- filename="01. Some title (Some album)"

$ album=""
$ filename="${track}. ${title}${album:+ ($album)}"
$ declare -p filename
declare -- filename="01. Some title"

$ unset album
$ filename="${track}. ${title}${album:+ ($album)}"
$ declare -p filename
declare -- filename="01. Some title"
```

ref: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning: The `${var:+value}` expansion is also working in _zsh_.

Comment: @mpy `${var:+value}` is in the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), so it'll also work in any POSIX-compliant shell (e.g. dash).